# CSS for setting up div to top up another division

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question, I am using a widget which has a text and I can customize the css for the division..

In the widget, the code to show the text and image is

```
<div>
<div class="image"><img src=""~~</div>
<div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

Now, am looking to let the text on top and the image after the text and in center, but I can not edit the html, so is there any way I could achieve it only through css??
I don't think using top margin-top would work up here, beacause it is a layout, and top or margin-top might breakout .

Thanks in Advance
Mohit

Answer (score 0):

If the markup and class names will be the same throughout, you could also use jQuery:

```
$('.image').each(function () {
    var container = $(this).parent('div');
    var image = $(this).detach();
    container.append(image);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9psQh/